# Как объединить 2 листа EXCEL в 1 по совпадающим значениям из первой колонки?

Tags: excel

[image: Первый лист]
[image: Второй лист]

На обоих листах первая колонка product_id совпадает. Как объединить эти 2 листа и записать все вариации со второй картинки в отдельные столбцы для каждого товара в первой?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(A2;Лист2!$A$2:$D$500;2;);)
```

`A2` - `ID` на первом листе (там, где записывается формула);
`Лист2!$A$2:$D$500` - диапазон данных второго листа;
2 - номер столбца `option` (для `option_value` будет 3, для `quantity` - 4).

Ели гарантированно все искомые `ID` есть на втором листе, формулу можно записать без функции `ЕСЛИОШИБКА`